# Why does scipy.signal.correlate2d fail to work in this example?

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to cross-correlate two images, and thus locate the template image on the first image, by finding the maximum correlation value.
I drew an image with some random shapes (first image), and cut out one of these shapes (template). Now, when I use scipy's correlate2d, and locate point in the correlation with maximum values, several point appear. From my knowledge, shouldn't there only be one point where the overlap is at max?

The idea behind this exercise is to take some part of an image, and then correlate that to some previous images from a database. Then I should be able to locate this part on the older images based on the maximum value of correlation.

My code looks something like this:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image 
import scipy.signal as sp

img = Image.open('test.png').convert('L')
img = np.asarray(img)

temp = Image.open('test_temp.png').convert('L')
temp = np.asarray(temp)
corr = sp.correlate2d(img, temp, boundary='symm', mode='full')

plt.imshow(corr, cmap='hot')
plt.colorbar()

coordin = np.where(corr == np.max(corr)) #Finds all coordinates where there is a maximum correlation

listOfCoordinates= list(zip(coordin[1], coordin[0]))

for i in range(len(listOfCoordinates)): #Plotting all those coordinates
    plt.plot(listOfCoordinates[i][0], listOfCoordinates[i][1],'c*', markersize=5)
```

This yields the figure:
[Cyan stars are points with max correlation value (255)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diiy6.png).

I expect there to be only one point in "corr" to have the max value of correlation, but several appear. I have tried to use different modes of correlating, but to no avail.

[This is the test image I use when correlating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JL2LW.png).
[This is the template, cut from the original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIUzJ.png).

Can anyone give some insight to what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: why would there only be one point of maximum correlation? Say for example you had 2 identical images, would you expect only 1 point of max correlation?

Comment: @DrBwts Well, the template I use is taken from the original image, so there should be exactly one point where there is 100% correlation, right? Other points might still be correlated, but not as much as the area the template is from.

Answer (score 2):

Applying

```
img = img - img.mean()
temp = temp - temp.mean()
```

before computing the 2D cross-correlation `corr` should give you the expected result.

Cleaning up the code, for a full example:

```py
from imageio.v3 import imread
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import scipy.signal as sp
import numpy as np

img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/JL2LW.png', pilmode='L')
temp = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIUzJ.png', pilmode='L')

corr = sp.correlate2d(img - img.mean(), 
                      temp - temp.mean(),
                      boundary='symm',
                      mode='full')

# coordinates where there is a maximum correlation
max_coords = np.where(corr == np.max(corr))

plt.plot(max_coords[1], max_coords[0],'c*', markersize=5)
plt.imshow(corr, cmap='hot')
plt.show()
```

Comment: It is better to use 'numpy.where(arr == numpy.amax(arr))[0]' for finding the coordinates of maximum as it returns an array of 2 values, instead of a tuple of arrays with one value

Answer (score 0):

You are probably overflowing the numpy type uint8.
Try using:

```
img = np.asarray(img,dtype=np.float32)
temp = np.asarray(temp,dtype=np.float32)
```

Untested.