# Why does correlate2d return noise?

Tags: python, scipy, computer-vision

I'm currently trying to create a bot for Minesweeper with computer vision. However using scipy.signal.correlate2d only yields noise. My test code is down below, why is the output just noise and not the heatmap I would expect?

```
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
from cv2 import cv2
from PIL import Image

image = cv2.imread('MinesweeperTest.png',0)
template = cv2.imread('Mine2.png',0)

corr = signal.correlate2d(image,template,mode="same")

Image.fromarray(corr).save("correlation.png")
```

All the images involved can be found here:

MinesweeperTest.png: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gxqtq.jpg

Mine2.png: https://i.stack.imgur.com/atV7T.jpg

Correlation.png: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aelY6.jpg

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57111113/scipy-signal-correlate2d-does-not-seem-to-work-as-intended/ which is a near-duplicate of this IMO!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preprocessing the images so that their mean value is 0 before invoking `correlate2d` should help get a more meaningful 2D cross-correlation:

```
image = image - image.mean()
template = template - template.mean()
```

A reproducible example reads:

```py
from imageio.v3 import imread
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np

image = imread('https://i.imgur.com/PpLLOW7.png', pilmode='L')
template = imread('https://i.imgur.com/ApIIs1Z.png', pilmode='L')

# fixed these
image = image - image.mean()
template = template - template.mean()

corr = signal.correlate2d(image, template, mode="same")
plt.imshow(corr, cmap='hot')
```