# Signal.Correlate2D/Signal.Convolution2D return unexpected and/or wrong results

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

So I'm trying to use correlation and convolution to find a sub-image (a "template") inside a larger image. In this case, I am trying to find this image:

[image]

Inside this image:

[image]

As you can see the template is actually just the first band/line in the second image. However, I've run into an issue that I don't understand. The first issue I ran into was the fact that both `correlate2D` and `convolve2D` returned noise to me. After looking through some SO posts, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59203554/why-does-correlate2d-return-noise) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57111113/why-does-scipy-signal-correlate2d-fail-to-work-in-this-example). I was not normalizing the image and template, which is why I got noise in return. After normalizing I was able to get an output that looked better:

[image]

The expected result here would be a lot of green between 0 and 100 and little to no green for the rest of the axis. Though as you can tell by looking at the image above, this is not what I got and I am confused as to why this is the case. Convolution is no better:

[image]

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I tried using `correlation2D` with the images from the second SO post I linked to above to confirm that it is working correctly and I can confirm it is working properly:

[image]

Why does it work for the image/template given in the second SO post and not for my image/template? Is it due to the quality of the images? Here is my code:

```py
import cv2
from scipy import signal
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Load images. The flag "0" means that the images should be loaded in grayscale.
image = cv2.imread(r"/home/user/Data/image.png", 0)
template = cv2.imread(r"/home/user/Data/template.png", 0)

# Normalize
image = image - image.mean()
template = template - template.mean()

# Apply correlation and convolution to images
correlation = signal.correlate2d(image, template)
convolution = signal.convolve2d(image, template)

# Show image
plt.imshow(correlation)
plt.imshow(convolution)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What version of OpenCV are you using?  In my version cv2.imread() returns only one value. You are doing a 1D template match, since the height of template and height of the image are the same. But if there is any vertical offset of the template from the image, it may not match well. Perhaps you should pad the image with gray on the top and bottom some so that you have room for the template to move up and down a little.

Comment: @fmw42 Sorry about that. imread() does return one value, it's previous code that I forgot to delete. I have now edited the post. 

As for your suggestion, I tried using `correlation` and `convolve` instead of their 2D counterpart and it didn't work. The height is the same for the template and the main image. I tried padding it and it didn't work either. I'm pretty sure I followed your instructions without any errors, but if anyone else has time for it then feel free to try this out yourself.

Comment: Have you tried cv2.matchTemplate()?

Comment: I know about `matchTemplate` and it works, but it's not really an answer to the question.